# Is it Possible to disable tableviewCell row swipe features except the selected row in swift 2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Suppose there are 10 row in table view cell if swipe any of the row and after press on the edit action field become editable and remaining row swipe should be disable.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{

     /*to perform edit action on row*/
    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Edit"){(UITableViewRowAction,NSIndexPath) -> Void in


    let cell:SuppliersCutomTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SuppliersCutomTableViewCell
        print("indexPath",indexPath)
/*making Field Editable method*/
     cell.textFieldedit()

    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.298, green: 0.851, blue: 0.3922, alpha: 1.0);

    return [edit]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `canEditRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableViewDataSource` for that, declare on `Bool` instance first like this and use this inside `UITableViewDataSource` methods.

```
var allowEdit: Bool = true

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return allowEdit
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{

    /*to perform edit action on row*/
    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Edit"){(UITableViewRowAction,NSIndexPath) -> Void in


        let cell:SuppliersCutomTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SuppliersCutomTableViewCell
        print("indexPath",indexPath)
        /*making Field Editable method*/
        cell.textFieldedit()
        self.allowEdit = false
    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.298, green: 0.851, blue: 0.3922, alpha: 1.0);

    return [edit]
}
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to set `self.allowEdit` to `true` when your edit done for that cell.

Comment: Welcome, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` method of `UITableView` and return Bool according to requirement.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    var canEdit = selectedCell == indexPath.row ? true : false
return canEdit

}
```